# Make paging prettier with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, pagination

Lets say there is a very large number of pages in my website:

```
<div class="caja_paginas">
    <ul class="paginas"> 
        <li class="actual"><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=4">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=5">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=6">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=7">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=8">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="/?tipo=links&amp;que=ultimas&amp;page=9">9</a></li>
          <!-- commented but i have like 1420 pages lol -->
         </ul>
</div>
```

And i need to make it prettier (you can check at http://goo.gl/DO1do )

So i was thinking doing something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li').hide();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual').show();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual').next('li').show();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual').prev('li').show();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li').last().html('last').show();
});
```

this would look like

**[1][2][last]**  //when actual/current is [1]

or

**[9][10][11][last]** //when is [10]; and so on

But how can i make it look

**[1][2][next][..][last]**

or

**[prev][..][9][10][11][next][..][last]**

respectively?

or maybe you have a better idea

-edit-

I edited a bit the code so it looks better

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
    var actual = $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual a").text();
    var actual_html = $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").html();
    var ultima = $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li a").last().text();
    var actual_html = $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").last().html();
    $(".caja_paginas #ellipsis").remove();
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li").hide();
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").show();
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").next("li").show().after('<li id="ellipsis">...</a></li>');
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").prev("li").show();
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li").first().show();
    if (actual > 4)
    {
        $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li").first().after('<li id="ellipsis">...</a></li>');
        $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas").prepend("<li>" + $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").prev().html() + "</li>");
        $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li a").first().text("<")
    }
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li").last().show();
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas").append("<li>" + $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual").next().html() + "</li>");
    $(".caja_paginas ul.paginas li a").last().text(">")
});
```

And can be tested/modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/q2WBG/1/

PD: for SEO terms, i would like to keep alllinks to pages in the HTML

Comment: If the links are hidden with .hide() search engines ignore them; you get no SEO benefit.

Comment: even if i hide() them on document.ready?

Comment: Even if you hide them on document.ready

Comment: @Joe are you sure? I highly doubt any search engine will ignore these links, as it'll mean the search engine will have to execute Javascript code (including the whole jQuery framework) THEN index the page. Can you point to some research that shows that SEO is affected hiding elements within Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Remove for in case you want to update it ever with JS
    $('.caja_paginas #ellipsis').remove();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li').hide();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual').show();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual').next('li').show().append('<li id="ellipsis">...</a></li>');
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual').prev('li').show();
    $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li').last().html('last').show();
});
```

Comment: Not bad; but i still don't know how to place the [next] and [prev] button... :(

Comment: Just re-use the .append(...) code. Wrap it in some logic to check what the text node of $('.caja_paginas ul.paginas li.actual') is, and if it's equal to the text node of the last one, don't show. And so on.

Comment: I edited my question with my progress. also 'append' was not valid because it would look like the last page.. what do you think , now?